# Methods for evaluating polynomials quickly

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, big-list

I am wondering what methods exist for effectively evaluating polynomials (manually or in the head) in a quick, efficient fashion.

For example, one of my favorite methods is the "nested form of a polynomial." Consider the following:

- $P(x) = 3x^4-5x^3+x^2-3x+5$
- $Q(x) = (((3x-5)x+1)x-3)x+5$

When $Q$ is expanded, it is clear that $P = Q$. When trying to evaluate, say, $P(2)$ and $Q(2)$, it becomes obvious that $Q(2)$ is *much* easier to evaluate.

Similarly, consider two more polynomial expressions:

- $R(x) = x^5-2x^4+3x^3+3x+4$
- $S(x) = (((x-2)x+3)x^2+3)x+4$

Again, it is easy to see that $R=S$ when $S$ is expanded. It is also clear that trying to evaluate $S(3)$ in your head is much easier than trying to evaluate $R(3)$.

Calculating with the nested form follows the same arithmetic steps as calculating the value of a polynomial using synthetic division. It is also very easy, as the above examples illustrate, to construct the nested form of a polynomial.

**Consideration:** What other methods or "tricks" exist that allow one to quickly evaluate polynomials?

Comment: [Horner's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method). Although it is actually just a neat way of writing down your nested form.

Comment: If it you happen to know that the powers are large compared to the number of sums ($x^{12}+2x^{4}+1$) you may want to compute the powers by successive squaring ($[((x^2)^2)^2+2](x^2)^2+1$) instead of Horner-Ruffini. If nothing is known Horner-Ruffini is the best.

Comment: The optimality of Horner's method (aka "nesting") in the absence of preprocessing was [discussed in the accepted answer to this MathOverflow post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/69476/fast-evaluation-of-polynomials).  I summarize what can be done with preprocessing in [this previous Math.SE answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/939691/3111), specifically that one can save nearly half the multiplications for a non-sparse polynomial.  I don't think these methods can by any stretch be considered suited for "in the head".